# SQL Where SUM() Between two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find account info for which the sum of `available_balance` is between two values. I tried to the following but it is not working as expected:

```
SELECT sum(a.avail_balance) `sum`
FROM account a
WHERE  `sum` BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
```

Result:`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sum' in 'where clause'`

How can I accomplish my intended result?

My table:

```
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| account_id | product_cd | cust_id | open_date  | close_date | last_activity_date | status | open_branch_id | open_emp_id | avail_balance | pending_balance |
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|          1 | CHK        |       1 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2005-01-04         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       1057.75 |         1057.75 |
|          2 | SAV        |       1 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2004-12-19         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |        500.00 |          500.00 |
|          3 | CD         |       1 | 2004-06-30 | NULL       | 2004-06-30         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       3000.00 |         3000.00 |
|          4 | CHK        |       2 | 2001-03-12 | NULL       | 2004-12-27         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       2258.02 |         2258.02 |
|          5 | SAV        |       2 | 2001-03-12 | NULL       | 2004-12-11         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |        200.00 |          200.00 |
|          7 | CHK        |       3 | 2002-11-23 | NULL       | 2004-11-30         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |       1057.75 |         1057.75 |
|          8 | MM         |       3 | 2002-12-15 | NULL       | 2004-12-05         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |       2212.50 |         2212.50 |
|         10 | CHK        |       4 | 2003-09-12 | NULL       | 2005-01-03         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        534.12 |          534.12 |
|         11 | SAV        |       4 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2004-10-24         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        767.77 |          767.77 |
|         12 | MM         |       4 | 2004-09-30 | NULL       | 2004-11-11         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       5487.09 |         5487.09 |
|         13 | CHK        |       5 | 2004-01-27 | NULL       | 2005-01-05         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |       2237.97 |         2897.97 |
|         14 | CHK        |       6 | 2002-08-24 | NULL       | 2004-11-29         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        122.37 |          122.37 |
|         15 | CD         |       6 | 2004-12-28 | NULL       | 2004-12-28         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |      10000.00 |        10000.00 |
|         17 | CD         |       7 | 2004-01-12 | NULL       | 2004-01-12         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       5000.00 |         5000.00 |
|         18 | CHK        |       8 | 2001-05-23 | NULL       | 2005-01-03         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |       3487.19 |         3487.19 |
|         19 | SAV        |       8 | 2001-05-23 | NULL       | 2004-10-12         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |        387.99 |          387.99 |
|         21 | CHK        |       9 | 2003-07-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        125.67 |          125.67 |
|         22 | MM         |       9 | 2004-10-28 | NULL       | 2004-10-28         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       9345.55 |         9845.55 |
|         23 | CD         |       9 | 2004-06-30 | NULL       | 2004-06-30         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       1500.00 |         1500.00 |
|         24 | CHK        |      10 | 2002-09-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |      23575.12 |        23575.12 |
|         25 | BUS        |      10 | 2002-10-01 | NULL       | 2004-08-28         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |          0.00 |            0.00 |
|         27 | BUS        |      11 | 2004-03-22 | NULL       | 2004-11-14         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       9345.55 |         9345.55 |
|         28 | CHK        |      12 | 2003-07-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |      38552.05 |        38552.05 |
|         29 | SBL        |      13 | 2004-02-22 | NULL       | 2004-12-17         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |      50000.00 |        50000.00 |
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use aggregates for comparison in the HAVING clause:

```
GROUP BY ...
  HAVING SUM(avail_balance) BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
```

The `HAVING` clause requires you to define a `GROUP BY` clause.

Assuming, you want to `SUM` the balance for each `cust_id`, you need something like

```
SELECT sum(a.avail_balance) `sum`
FROM account a
GROUP BY `cust_id` 
HAVING SUM(a.avail_balance) BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(a.avail_balance)'sum'
FROM account a
WHERE  a.avail_balance between 5000 and 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions(AVG,COUNT,MIN,MAX,SUM) for comparison can be achieved by using the "HAVING" clause which requires "GROUP BY" clause(relevant category column depending on the requirement).

As rightly pointed by Pankaj Gadge, cust_id is the most suitable for the requirement of the problem statement

```
SELECT SUM(a.avail_balance) 'Sum'
FROM account a
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING SUM(a.avail_balance) BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause
ex: group by column_name
having sum(avail_balance) between 5000 and 10000